# 401 on request where `permitAll()` specified

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security, spring-security

I have this WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter config:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class HttpSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()

                .mvcMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()

                .anyRequest().authenticated()

                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt()
        ;
    }
}
```

When I make a request to `auth`, I get a 401, until I pass some authorisation - which isn't appropriate for this endopint.

I would assume this has something to do with `.anyRequest().authenticated()`. I had read before that this shouldn't affect the `permitAll()`s - have I misconfigured something?

Comment: Do you have an example of the path which return 401

Comment: Did you annotate your configuration class with @EnableWebSecurity ?

Comment: @AkifHadziabdic "POST /auth/test"

Comment: @Nemanja yes `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request is probably being rejected because you didn't provide a [CSRF token](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#csrf-considerations). By default, Spring Security enables it for every `POST` request and you need to explicitly disable it.

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class HttpSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .mvcMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
    }
}
```

You can add the following property to your `application.yml` file so you can be able to see why your request is being rejected if CSRF is not the case:

```yaml
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: TRACE
```

Comment: This was in fact the problem

Answer (score 0):

If u are using jwt filter,it won't work even if you added permitAll() .if you remove the filter, it will work fine.

Comment: The only workaround I know is to ignore HttpMethod.POST, so all urls with the POST method will be ignored.

Comment: You can take a look at this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4368 Seems like there are another workounds